# Ensemble average of square of fluctuations proof

Tags: statistics, summation

The ensemble average of a random variable $x$ is denoted as $X$ or $\left \langle x \right \rangle$, and is defined as:

$$ X = \left \langle x \right \rangle = \lim_{N \to \infty} \frac{1}{N} \sum_{n=1}^{N} x_n$$

Now, if $x$ had a fluctuation about a mean value $X$ we can express $x$ as a function of mean $X$ and fluctuations $x'$:
$$ x' = x - X $$

obviously, the ensemble average of fluctuations $x' = 0$; $( \left \langle x' \right \rangle = 0 )$, but this is not the case for $\left \langle (x')^2 \right \rangle$. The ensemble average of $x'^2$ is called **variance** $var[x]$

$$ var[x] = \left \langle (x')^2 \right \rangle = \left \langle (x- X)^2 \right \rangle =  \lim_{N \to \infty} \frac{1}{N} \sum_{n=1}^{N} [x_n-X]^2$$

I'm supposed to prove that $var[x] = \left \langle x^2 \right \rangle - X^2$. however, I'm stuck at the following step:

$$var[x] = \left \langle (x')^2 \right \rangle = \left \langle (x-X)^2 \right \rangle = \left \langle (x^2+X^2-2xX) \right \rangle  = \lim_{N \to \infty} \frac{1}{N} \sum_{n=1}^{N} (x^2+X^2-2xX)$$

How should I proceed?

Comment: Note that since $X$ is a real number we have $\left<xX\right> = X\left<x\right> = \left<x\right>^2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're almost there! Just remember linearity:

$$var[x] = \left \langle (x')^2 \right \rangle = \left \langle (x-X)^2 \right \rangle = \left \langle (x^2+X^2-2xX) \right \rangle  = \lim_{N \to \infty} \frac{1}{N} \sum_{n=1}^{N} (x_n^2+X^2-2x_n X)=\lim_{N \to \infty} \frac{1}{N} \sum_{n=1}^{N} x_n^2+\lim_{N \to \infty} \frac{1}{N} \sum_{n=1}^{N} X^2-\lim_{N \to \infty} \frac{1}{N} \sum_{n=1}^{N} 2x_n X$$

Can you finish?

Comment: YES, $$\lim_{N \to \infty} \frac{1}{N} \sum_{n=1}^{N} x_n^2 = \left \langle x^2 \right \rangle \, \& \lim_{N \to \infty} \frac{1}{N} \sum_{n=1}^{N} X^2 = X^2 \, \& \lim_{N \to \infty} \frac{1}{N} \sum_{n=1}^{N} 2x_nX = 2X^2$$ Yielding: $$\left \langle x^2 \right \rangle - X^2$$

Comment: @Algo Yup, looks good!